# how to bind controls to files on directories on hard drive?

Tags: c#, ado.net, save, wizard

is there any way to use visual studio wizards  to create a entry form to retrieve and save data from database and Simultaneously corresponding files from directories on hard drive.to use less coding

Comment: What type of database would you be using? Is it just a basic one using a text file or is it a SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware I don't think that there is a way to save files to a database just using the wizards however it is a fairly easy thing to do:

```
Streamwriter sw = new Streamwriter(FilePath);
sw.WriteLine(/*database entries*/);
```

Using something like this you should be easily able to implement this in a few lines of code.

See this post on MSDN for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Also if you are having difficulties reading the database into your code you can just use:

```
string str = StreamReaderTest.ReadToEnd();
str.Split(/*entry delimiter*/);
```